# Error occurs when changing facet labels in facet_grid and add geom_vline at the same time

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I am trying to change the facet labels without revising the data frame, and add a vertical line to the plot to enhance understandability.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(weeks = rep(-3:3, each = 2),
                 is_manual = rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), times = 7),
                 value = c(rnorm(7, 10), rnorm(7, 20)))

# Plotting
ggplot(df, aes(x = weeks, y = value)) + geom_line() +
  facet_grid(is_manual ~ .) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = "blue", linetype = 2)
```

gives me this, which works fine:

[image: plot1.png]

Now I'd like to change the facet labels so that everyone knows what TRUE and FALSE are.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = weeks, y = value)) + geom_line() +
  facet_grid(ifelse(is_manual, "Manual", "Uploaded") ~ .) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = "blue", linetype = 2)
```

, but it returns an error:

> Error in ifelse(is_manual, "Manual", "Uploaded"): object 'is_manual' not found

However, once I remove the `geom_vline` part, it works as normal, which means 'is_manual' should be able to be found.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = weeks, y = value)) + geom_line() +
  facet_grid(ifelse(is_manual, "Manual", "Uploaded") ~ .)
```

[image: plot2.png]

I can work around by doing

```
df$is_manual <- ifelse(df$is_manual, "Manual", "Uploaded")
ggplot(df, aes(x = weeks, y = value)) + geom_line() +
  facet_grid(is_manual ~ .) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = "blue", linetype = 2)
```

, but it changes my underlying data.

Is there a way that I can change the facet labels and add the vertical line at the same time while *not* changing the data frame contents? Or is this a bug which needs reporting?

Comment: For people who may be interested, I've opened an [issue #2489](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2489) on GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just guessing here, but maybe `geom_vline` is getting the facet label names from the original data frame `df` passed to `ggplot`, rather than from the updated formula used in `facet_grid`, causing an error when `geom_vline` can't figure out where the facets are.

In any case, instead of changing your underlying data, you can update it on the fly using the `dplyr` pipe (`%>%`) and avoid the error:

```
library(tidyverse) 

ggplot(df %>% mutate(is_manual = ifelse(is_manual, "Manual", "Uploaded"),
       aes(x = weeks, y = value)) + geom_line() +
  facet_grid(is_manual ~ .) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = "blue", linetype = 2)
```

Comment: It comes up to my mind that: does your theory stand if `ggplot(df, aes(x = weeks, y = value)) + geom_line() + geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = "blue", linetype = 2) + facet_grid(ifelse(is_manual, "Manual", "Uploaded") ~ .)` shows the same error? In this case the vertical line is drawn in _prior_ to faceting. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it matters where the `facet_grid` statement is located in the sequence, as the data has to be split by facet(s) before the geoms are generated, regardless. Only the geom order matters.